# Prove that if $a_n$ is increasing and $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = L$, then $L > a_n$ for all n.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification

Prove that if $a_n$ is increasing and $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = L$, then $L > a_n$ for all n.

I am given this definition of an increasing sequence

$$\text{A sequence } a_n \text{ is increasing if for any } m \text{ and } n \text{ with } n > m, \text{ we have } a_n > a_m$$

along with the definition of a limit

$$\text{For every } \epsilon > 0, \text{there exists an } N \text{ such that for every } n \geq N, \left|a_n - L\right| < \epsilon$$

What I came up with:

Suppose $L \leq a_n$. Let $\epsilon = a_m - L$. Then,

$$\left|a_n - L\right| < \epsilon$$
$$a_n - L < \epsilon$$
$$a_n - L < a_m - L$$
$$a_n < a_m$$

Which is supposed to prove by contradiction that $L > a_n$.

This seems very wrong to me though, and so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd rather let $\epsilon=a_{n+1}-L$.

Comment: Do you mean to do that instead of trying to prove by contradiction? Also, do I not need to do anything with m, or is that what n+1 is supposed to stand for?

Answer (score 1):

In your attempt, "suppose $L\le a_n$" is not complete.

Suppose $L\leq a_n$ for **some** $n$ (which is the negation of "$L>a_n$ for all $n$"). Then $a_{n+1}>L$ since the sequence is increasing.

Now look at the interval $I=(L,a_{n+1})$. Since the sequence is increasing, there would be no $a_m$ in $I$ for **all** $m\geq n+1$. This contradicts the assumption that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=L
$$

Answer (score 0):

You don't know if $\varepsilon=a_m-L>0$, you only have $\varepsilon\geqslant 0$. Also, what is $m$ ? I guess $m>n$, thus $a_{m}-L>a_n-L\geqslant 0$ so that $\varepsilon=a_{m}-L>0$. You finally state that $a_n<a_m$ which is not a condradiction because $m>n$. Moreover you can't solve it by taking $m<n$ because you would not necessary have $\varepsilon >0$. You can prove you result this way : let $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then
$$ \forall m>n+1,a_{n+1}< a_m $$
Letting $m\rightarrow +\infty$ gives you $a_{n+1}\leqslant L$, but $a_n<a_{n+1}$, thus $a_n<L$.